# Is "~ has it that ~" colloquial or can it be used in formal writings?

Tags: phrase-usage

The following are examples of "〜 has it that 〜":

> • **Conventional wisdom has it that** riots only ever happen in cities.
> ([oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/wisdom))
>
> • **rumor has it that...** there is a rumor that... Rumor **has it that** Fred is seeing Mary and that they are engaged.
> ([thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rumor+has+it+that))

Is this pattern colloquial, or can it be used in formal writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this phrasing is acceptable in formal writing, though it is idiomatic. It's typically used for attributing something to an abstract, nebulous or potentially questionable source (e.g. rumor, conventional wisdom, legend, work which is hotly contested), though such items are not mandatory to the idiom.

The construction somewhat distances the expressed idea (e.g. *riots only happen in cities*) from the speaker, by emphasizing the source and making it the sentence's subject. Additionally, it expresses some degree of equivocation, ambiguity or vagueness (especially if the source is something hazy, like common sense), further distancing the idea from the speaker; [Wikipedia lists it (paired with such a source) as an example on the 'weasel word' page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word#Forms). Such nuanced expression can be quite useful in a formal register.

[Searching Google Scholar for the phrase](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22has%20it%20that%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=) yields approximately 59,000 results, though some of these are listed as citations only.